# Page navigation on Label tap throws Exception

Tags: xml, nativescript

I am a newbie NativeScript developer with a web development background. I am creating a basic app with (currently) two main pages: `login-page.xml` and `signup-page.xml`.

Here's the directory structure:

```
app
|-- app-root.xml
|-- app.css
|-- app.js

|-- signup
    |-- signup-page.xml

|-- login
    |-- login-page.xml
    |-- login-page.js
```

What I am trying to do is to establish navigation to and from `login` and `signup`.

After going through the instructions [here](https://docs.nativescript.org/core-concepts/navigation#frame), I came up with the following idea to navigate to `signup-page.xml` when a **Label** is **tapped**.

```
<!--login/login-page.xml-->
<Label class="small-text" text="Join us" tap="goto" />
```

...

```
<!--login-page.js-->
exports.goto = function (args) {
    args.object.page.frame.navigate("~/signup/signup-page");
}
```

...

```
<!--app-root.xml-->
<Frame defaultPage="login/login-page"></Frame>
```

This code, however, is not working. Every time the **Label** on `login-page.xml` is tapped, an exception is thrown. Here's the error message:

```
An uncaught Exception occurred on "main" thread.
com.tns.NativeScriptException:
Calling js method onTouch failed
```

I have made sure that the function **goto()** is being invoked upon tapping the label and the `signup-page.xml` page is independently woking.

How do I set up a simple navigation mechanism like it happens on webpages through the `<a>` tag??

Comment: Can you create Playground example where we can reproduce the issue? Between, with NativeScript you reuse your web skills like JavaScript / CSS / XML (not HTML) to build native mobile apps. Browser specific features are not supported here. But if you use `nativescript-angular` you may use the `routerLink` features which is similar to anchor (`<a>`) navigation.

Answer (score 0):

I finally found the solution.

It seems that the variable **frame** is undefined. As used to general object oriented paradigm, I mistook it to be a **property** of `args.object.page`.

For general (forward) navigation, we can use the **frame module** of NativeScript. Here's a **Js** example:

```
var frame = require("ui/frame");
...
...
exports.goto = function(){
    frame.topmost().navigate("signup/signup-page");
}
```

**NOTE**: The **path** specified as the *argument* to the `navigate()` function is with respect to the **directory structure** shown in the question. Yes, it seems weird, but, although the `signup` directory is outside the current (login) directory, we do not have to refer to it with respect to the root directory.

Answer (score 0):

`args.object.page.frame.navigate(...)` seems to just work fine, only that you have to specify just the module name relative to app folder.

```
<!--login-page.js-->
exports.goto = function (args) {
   args.object.page.frame.navigate("signup/signup-page");
}
```

You don't need the extra tilde (`~`) symbol at the front which we usually use with file-system to denote app the folder.

[Sample Project](https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-js&id=09S7pk)